# ctrl+e doesn't clear output window but exits SAS program?

Tags: sas

when i tried to clear the output window using ctrl+e, it terminated SAS. My SAS version is 9.3M2. Has anyone encountered the same problem? Thanks.

Comment: Type `keys` into the command box (upper left hand corner next to the check mark).  What does it say under CTRL+E?

Comment: I've seen this in our 9.3 IDEs.  Usually an interactive process (like SQL, REG, IML, etc) is running.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I checked the keys and ctrl+E is defined as clear. Yes, i was using SQL when this happened. Will contact tech support as suggested by Joe.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a hot fix for this.  It is supposed to be fixed in 9.3TSM2, so if it is not you may need to contact SAS support.

The kb article with the hot fix is located currently [here](http://support.sas.com/kb/45/003.html) (kb# 45003).

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what you are asking, we hot-key the clearing of the log and output so someone doesn't accidentally CTRL-E their program window.

1. Type `keys` in the command box
2. Type `output;clear;log;clear;wpgm` into the command for a key (we use F12)

This will clear the log and output windows and bring the current program editor to focus.